# dictionaries at 'record_path' does not get flattened in json_normalize

Tags: pandas

Below is the json data structure, which I am trying to convert to CSV

```
[{
            "ASIN": "B0773V2Z6",
            "Condition": "NewItem",
            "EarliestAvailability": {
                "TimepointType": "Immediately"
            },
            "FNSKU": "B0773V2Z6",
            "InStockSupplyQuantity": "18",
            "SellerSKU": "30237",
            "SupplyDetail.member": [
                    {
                        "EarliestAvailableToPick": {
                            "TimepointType": "Immediately"
                        },
                        "LatestAvailableToPick": {
                            "TimepointType": "Immediately"
                        },
                        "Quantity": "1",
                        "SupplyType": "InStock"
                    },
                    {
                        "EarliestAvailableToPick": {
                            "TimepointType": "Immediately"
                        },
                        "LatestAvailableToPick": {
                            "TimepointType": "Immediately"
                        },
                        "Quantity": "1",
                        "SupplyType": "InStock"
                    }
           ],
           "TotalSupplyQuantity": "18",            
}]
```

I have tried to use json_normalize from pandas lib as below

```
df = json_normalize(json_data, record_path="SupplyDetail.member", meta=["ASIN"], errors='ignore')
```

It gives following result

```
EarliestAvailableToPick              LatestAvailableToPick              ASIN
{'TimepointType': 'Immediately'}    {'TimepointType': 'Immediately'}    B0773V2Z6T
{'TimepointType': 'Immediately'}    {'TimepointType': 'Immediately'}    B0773V2Z6T
```

I need the result as

```
EarliestAvailableToPick.TimepointType   LatestAvailableToPick.TimepointType   ASIN
'Immediately'                           'Immediately'                         B0773V2Z6T
'Immediately'                           'Immediately'                         B0773V2Z6T
```

I know that if the dictionaries are at first level of json, json_normalize flattens it. But if we are using 'record_path', it is not flattening dictinaries under that path!
Please help

Comment: looks like a bug to me.  you can see that when no record path is included, a different code path is traversed: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/io/json/normalize.py#L191-L201. to get the behavior you want, `nested_to_record` needs to be called, but it is never called if you pass in `record_path`

Comment: @BobBaxley, you are right. But is it a bug or limitation put, I don't know. How I solved the problem is, do the `json_normalise` again on the first dataframe. I will put my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to reach desired solution.

`df = json_normalize(json_data, record_path="SupplyDetail.member", meta=["ASIN"], errors='ignore')
re_data = df.to_json(orient='records')
df_new = json_normalize(json.loads(re_data))`

The result(`df_new`) is:

`EarliestAvailableToPick.TimepointType LatestAvailableToPick.TimepointType Quantity SupplyType ASIN
'Immediately'                         'Immediately'                       1           InStock               B0773V2Z6
'Immediately'                         'Immediately'                       1           InStock               B0773V2Z6`

Answer (score -1):

As a quick and dirty fix, you can do the following:

```
df['EarliestAvailableToPick.TimepointType'] = df.EarliestAvailableToPick.map(lambda d: d['TimepointType'])
df['LatestAvailableToPick.TimepointType'] = df.LatestAvailableToPick.map(lambda d: d['TimepointType'])
```